# Using unique_ptr member variables or not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, blockingqueue

What is a better designpattern for creating a blocking bufferqueue, that uses resources efficiently in C++11/14 without too many allocs/moves? Using `Queue<std::unique_ptr<Workitem>>`

OR

`Queue<Workitem>` and with that hiding the resource management in the implementation (a bit like stl containers). Note, the second idea (Queue) is commented out. What are the implications of the commented out version also regarding heap/stack? And what about using `std::unique_ptr<Queue<Workitem>> q`?

I am not very good with c++, but regardless of the version, I can't really leak memory right? (reasonging: not new/delete -> no memoryleaks)

Code here:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <mutex>
#include <queue>

template <class T> class Queue {
public:
  Queue(size_t size);

  // push item to _queue if _queue.size() < _size
  // else block
  void push(T item);
  // void push(std::unique_ptr<T> item);

  // pop item if !_queue.empty()
  // else block or return false after timeout
  bool pop(T &item);
  // bool pop(std::unique_ptr<T> &item);

private:
  std::mutex _mutex;
  std::size_t _size;

  std::queue<T> _queue;
  // std::queue<std::unique_ptr<T>> _queue;

  std::condition_variable _condition_full;
  std::condition_variable _condition_empty;
};

struct Workitem {
  size_t idx;
  void *workdetails;
};

void do_work(Queue<std::unique_ptr<Workitem>> &work_q,
             Queue<std::unique_ptr<Workitem>> &write_q,
             struct options_s &opts) {
  std::unique_ptr<Workitem> work;
  while (work_q.pop(work)) {
    // calculation w/ work
    std::unique_ptr<Workitem> res = consume(work, opts);
    write_q.push(std::move(work));
  }
}
void do_write(Queue<std::unique_ptr<Workitem>> &write_q,
              struct options_s &opts) {
  std::unique_ptr<Workitem> work;
  while (write_q.pop(work)) {
    prepare_for_writing(work, opts); // clean item
    write(work);
  }
}

auto w1 = std::thread(do_work, std::ref(work_q), std::ref(write_q),
                      std::ref(options));
auto w2 = std::thread(do_work, std::ref(work_q), std::ref(write_q),
                      std::ref(options));
auto writer = std::thread(do_write, std::ref(write_q), std::ref(options));

int main() {
  Queue<std::unique_ptr<Workitem>> work_q{4};
  Queue<std::unique_ptr<Workitem>> write_q{4};
  // Queue<Workitem> q{4};
  // ??? std::unique_ptr<Queue<Workitem>> q{4} ???

  for (size_t i, ...) { // do many iterations
    std::unique_ptr<Workitem> w{};
    // Workitem w{};

    populate(w, i); // populate work item

    work_q.push(std::move(w));
  }

  w1.join();
  w2.join();
  writer.join();
}
```

I can give the implementation if that helps, I just didn't want to clutter everything so I left it out. As a remark, the queue is used by threads. I use two queues for multiple worker threads and one writer thread to spread the load across cores.

cheers

Comment: I don't see what using a `unique_ptr` buys you in this situation tbh, the internal `std::queue<T>` already stores its internal data on the heap.

Comment: Workdetails may leak.

Comment: Its not for work, don't worry. I thought that, with using threads, just passing a smart pointer is better. I am going to add some more details to show what I mean

Comment: @Galik So if I do not use smartpointers and pop from std::queue, do I wrap it in a smartpointer via make_shared and pass it on, or is using smart pointers here completely unnecessary and just adds bloat?

Comment: Your queue should ideally be item-agnostic. If you need to store smart pointers let the consumer of the queue make that call; not the queue itself. Ex: you're storing polymorphic objects with an interface-base (unique or shared) would be a logical choice, but a choice for the code *using* the queue; not the queue. Coding a queue where the items allow for efficient move-concepts (and in the case of unique-ptr, required) is a bit more work, but probably what you ultimately want regardless.

Comment: So, I better overload the push/pop functions for move semantics instead of making the queue use unique_ptr in its implementation? What exactly do you mean by _...choice for the code using the queue; not the queue_ ?

Comment: You can just accept your parameters by value exactly as you are doing now. That allows you to *move* items in if you want and if you don't move they will just copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is a better designpattern for creating a blocking bufferqueue, that uses resources efficiently in C++11/14 without too many allocs/moves? Using `Queue<std::unique_ptr<Workitem>>` OR `Queue<Workitem>`

Given that criteria, `Queue<Workitem>` is better because it avoids one layer of dynamic allocation.

> What are the implications of the commented out version also regarding heap/stack?

There aren't really any differences regarding heap versus stack. The objects are dynamically allocated in both variations.

> I can't really leak memory right? (reasonging: not new/delete -> no memoryleaks)

Your reasoning is sound. The example code that you show has no memory leaks.

There however is a bare pointer member variable `Workitem::workdetails` that may have potential for memory leaks if it is misused (if it ever owns memory that it points to).

Comment: Okay, what about maximum heap size? Because in `struct Workitem` there will be a buffer of around 1Mb thats going to be populated by do_work and written by do_write. I kinda got the impression to minimize heap usage by using std::unique_ptr instead.
Also, Std::queue is going to use the copy operator on `struct Workitem` if i just use `Queue<Workitem>` right?

Comment: @JonasK no, there will be more heap usage with `std::unique_ptr`, because then both the pointed `Workitem` instance (allocated separately), and the `std::unique_ptr` itself (within the queue) are dynamically allocated. Not only that, but the object is allocated separately, and there is memory overhead for every allocation.

Comment: `std::queue` can copy or move `Workitem` depending on how you use it. It shouldn't matter much, since `Workitem` is quite small (probably twice the size of `std::unique_ptr`) and therefore very fast to copy and move. The allocation overhead of `std::unique_ptr` will probably be much more significant than this size difference.

Comment: whoops, I meant stack usage sorry. But I see your point, thanks.

Comment: @JonasK The elements of `std::queue` are not allocated on stack.

Comment: Yes, but wouldn't that be even better? Allocate Workitem via unique_ptr, move it into queue, then into the respective thread where it is consumed?